# Windows 7 Browsers Ignoring DIV height 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, windows-7

I am using the jQuery UI.Layout plugin and on OSX in Chrome, FF, and Safari, all is hunky dory.  However, on Windows (7) on Firefox, Chrome, and IE8 I am getting the following:

> The layout container
>   "DIV/#project-container" has no
>   height.

So the DIV isn't visible.  My div is very simply defined like so:

```
<div id="project-container" style='height: 100%'>
....
</div>
```

So what gives?  If I say height: 100px it renders.  Why is this only happening on Windows browsers (other than the obvious windows bashing reasons).

Comment: how high is the outer div? The inner div will only take 100% of the parent element.

Comment: It's not an issue of the height not being right. It's an issue of the height percentage being ignored completely, or something.  So when the jQuery plugin tries to get the height, it returns 0 instead of 100%.  I'm going to do some pure jQuery testing around this, but that is the essence of the issue, I think.

Comment: Actually, seems like that *is* this issue.  The parent didn't have a specific height specified.  After I made it 100%, the inner div was fine.  Still not sure why this isn't an issue on OSX and is an issue on Windows.

Comment: Well, it did and it didn't.  Still having height issues.  But probably differently related.

Comment: The normal reason something like this would happen on Windows but not Mac is browser-sniffing in the site code.  Past that, the only layout difference in at least Firefox should be due to different fonts... at least assuming you're testing the same version on Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to make sure that you apply 100% height to your body & html tags as well:

```
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```